# Does Laravel Homestead come with Nginx or Apache installed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead, laravel-5.6

I am very new to Laravel and i love coding locally so of course i am using Homestead. Does Homestead use Nginx or Apache? A question before i send my site online when i get it completed.

Laravel 5.6 is the current and latest. I am using that. I am also using the latest version of Homestead as of 5/7/2018.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Homestead goes with Nginx but it's also possible to use Apache.

You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead :

> Homestead uses the Nginx web server by default. However, it can install Apache if apache is specified as a site type. While both web servers can be installed at the same time, they cannot both be running at the same time. The `flip` shell command is available to ease the process of switching between web servers. The `flip` command automatically determines which web server is running, shuts it off, and then starts the other server. To use this command, SSH into your Homestead machine and run the command in your terminal:
>
> flip

Comment: Thank you Marcin for your response. I was thinking it was Nginx but was unsure if it was really that and i am unsure on how to check (rather leave the homestead files and settings alone anyways). :D Thank you! :D

Comment: `flip` existed in the documentation back in the 2018, but now with version 9 it has gone. Does it mean that now there is a way to run both web servers can at the same time?